# Dynamic Template not working for short, byte & float

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to create a template, in my template I am trying to achieve the dynamic mapping.

Here is what I wrote, as in **6.2.1** the only boolean, date, double, long, object, string are automatically detected, facing issues for mapping the float, short & byte.

Here if I index **127**, it will be mapped to **short** from the **short_fields**, it's fine, but when I index some 325566, I am getting exception Numeric value (325566) out of range of Java short, I want to suppress this and let **long_fields**, should take care about this & it should be mapped to long. I have tried with `coerce:false`, `ignore_malformed:true`, none of them worked as expected.

```
"dynamic_templates": [
  {
    "short_fields": {
      "match": "*",
      "match_mapping_type": "long",
      "mapping": {
        "type": "short",
        "doc_values": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "long_fields": {
      "match": "*",
      "match_mapping_type": "long",
      "mapping": {
        "type": "long",
        "doc_values": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "byte_fields": {
      "match": "*",
      "match_mapping_type": "byte",
      "mapping": {
        "type": "byte",
        "doc_values": true
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to make Elasticsearch choose the smallest data type possible for you. There are plenty of workarounds, but let me first explain why it does not work.

### Why it does not work?

[Dynamic mapping templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-templates.html) allow to override default dynamic type matching in three ways:

- by matching the name of the field,
- by matching the type Elasticsearch have guessed for you,
- and by a path in the document.

Elasticsearch picks the first matching rule that works. In your case, the first rule, `short_fields`, always works for any integer, because it accepts any field name and a guessed type `long`.

That's why it works for 127 but doesn't work for 325566.

To illustrate better this point, let's change `"matching_mapping_type"` in the first rule like this:

```
"match_mapping_type": "short",
```

Elasticsearch does not accept it and returns an error:

```
  {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [doc]: No field type matched on [short], \
possible values are [object, string, long, double, boolean, date, binary]"
  }
```

### But how can we make Elasticsearch pick the right types?

Here are some of the options.

#### Define strict mapping manually

This gives you full control over the selection of types.

#### Use the default `long`

Postpone "shrinking" data until it starts being a performance problem.

In fact, using smaller data types will [only affect searching/indexing performance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/number.html#_which_type_should_i_use), not the storage required. As long as you are fine with dynamic mappings, Elasticsearch manages them for you pretty well.

#### Mark field names with type information

Since Elasticsearch is not able to tell a byte from long, you can determine the type beforehand and add type information in the field name, like `customerAge_byte` or `revenue_long`.

Then you will be able to use a prefix/suffix [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/dynamic-templates.html#match-unmatch) like this:

```
    {
      "bytes_as_longs": {
        "match_mapping_type": "long",
        "match":   "*_byte",
        "mapping": {
          "type": "byte"
        }
      }
    }
```

Please choose the approach that fit your needs better.

### Why Elasticsearch takes longs

The reason why Elasticsearch takes longs for any integer input is probably coming from the JSON definition of a number type (as shown at [json.org](https://www.json.org/)):

[image: JSON number definition - from json.org]

It is not possible to tell if a number `0` or `1` is actually integer or long *in the entire dataset*. Elasticsearch has to guess the correct type from the first example shown, and it takes the safest shot possible.

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Alot !!!!!!!!!!!! @nikolay,So in the latest versions,we cant use the byte,short & float.If at all we want we have to  define strict mapping ?                  As according to my requirement, the filed names ,cant be added with any suffix or prefix due to some restrictions ,so its better to have strict mapping?

Comment: @prasadkp Yes, if you can, defining mapping beforehand is the best solution. You can also have only part of the mapping strict, pls checkout the [documentation of dynamic vs. strict](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html) for further details.